# EOS 500D can I charge while using it?

Tags: canon-500d

I am a free time Twitch streamer and I wondered if there is some way to charge the camera while using it, is it possible or do I need to have some accessories to the battery

Best regards Bastian Sand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to charge a battery while it is inserted in your EOS 500D. If you need to leave the camera on longer than a full battery can power it, you need a coupler that uses a dummy battery inside the camera connected to an external power source such as a wall outlet. There's a rubber flap on your camera that moves out of the way next to the battery compartment door that lets the cord run through.

Page 193 of the *[EOS 500D Instruction Manual](https://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft33601/manual/EOS500D_EN_Flat.pdf)*:

[image]

Canon made them for the 500D back in the day, but has long since discontinued that accessory along with the 500D. [Third party versions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QLKZ9Y9) are still available.